# Writing in a file through socket

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi4

So, I have a Rpi, connected to a python code by socket. I wanted to know if it was possible to write on a file on the Rpi from my python code...?

For my python code, I use the usual serve code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

And what I would like to do is read a file on the client, something like this:

```
conn.open('path/file.txt')
```

Obviously, with this line, an error says that socket doesn't have a method call read.
Will it be possible to open that file in any other way?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No.  The client code needs to send the file, and the two sides need to agree on a protocol.  The right way to do what you're asking is to use `scp`.  You already have an ssh server on your Pi, right?

Comment: If you want to write the transfer code yourself, you would use `socket.socket` to open a connection on the client, open the file normally, then write a loop that reads the file and sends to the socket, paying attention to the send's return value to avoid partial sends.

Comment: @TimRoberts For the scp, can the connection happens at the same time as the socket if they are only link by one ethernet cable? I think the port will be busy, but I will make sure to try at least!

Comment: You can answer that question, can't you?  You can have your mail app and your web browser open, listen to Spotify and watch a YouTube video all at the same time, right?

Comment: Ahahah! Ok, I got it! Thanks a lot for you help and time! :)